# How to resize a photo in TextEdit?

Tags: macos, textedit

When I add photos to TextEdit, they sometimes  appear too big, and I want to make them smaller.

How can I resize or modify photos in TextEdit?

Comment: What version of OS X? What version of Text Edit?

Comment: You mentioned that the image sometimes appear too big. I too had this problem sometimes when pasting an image in TextEdit. I usually paste the image in Pages and resize it there and copy that image and then paste it in TextEdit. This solved the problem for me. (I miss MS Paint of Windows OS which lets me dynamically resize the images by resizing the image canvas)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TextEdit** has no *direct* image editing options.

You can, though, once you've added an image into the document, *double click* it to open it with **Preview**.

Through Preview you'll be able to perform some *basic* image editing such as *size adjustment* (**Tools / Adjust Size**) or adding *figures* or text (**View / Show Edit Toolbar**).

Comment: If I change the size in Preview but don't change the resolution, then it is still the same size for me in TextEdit, as if TextEdit can only draw bitmaps at 72dpi. Is it possible to have a higher-resolution picture in TextEdit, as would be appropriate for printed output?

Comment: The changes you make in Preview are directly reflected in TextEdit.

Answer (score 4):

**Like Thecafremo already said:**
You can, once you've added an image into the document, double click it to open it with **Preview**.

Through Preview you'll be able to perform some basic image editing such as size adjustment (**Tools / Adjust Size**).

**My addition:**
Adjust "**Resolution**" to something larger, i.e. 300 dpi and make sure you **uncheck** "resample image".
Now save it (or quit preview: the image will be saved automatically) and the size will be adjusted right away in Text Edit!

Comment: Would probably recommend adding this as a comment to Thecafremo's post next time. But comments don't allow bold for uncheck so maybe this is okay too?